# Logback-spring.xml creating multiple log files when configured with springProfile

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, spring-logback

I am getting an issue while adding `<springProfile>` in my logback-spring.xml. In my case, I need to get the file name as well as path from the application.properties file and provide a date based rolling policy. So I can't specify the file name and path in logback-spring.xml.

So whenever I run the project specific to the profile from my IDE or by executable jar file, I am getting two log files created, one at the current working directory and the other at the specified file path location mentioned in the application.properties file.

I have three profiles based on the three different environments i.e. Local, Dev and Prod.

for local I am using spring OOTB application.properties file.

```
spring.profiles.active=local
server.port=8080

#logging 

logging.level.root=info
logging.level.com.myApp=trace
logging.file.path=C:/Spring/logs
logging.file.name=app-Log
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

and for dev and prod i am using application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties respectively.

application-dev.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.port=9090

#logging 

logging.level.root=info
logging.level.com.myApp=trace
logging.file.path=C:/Spring/logs/dev
logging.file.name=app-Log
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

Here is my logback-spring.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include
        resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <springProfile name="prod">
        <property resource="application-prod.properties" />
        <appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}.log</file>

            <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %X{host} %X{port} [%thread] %X{clientapp} %-5level %-40.40logger{39} : %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
                </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>

        </appender>
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="uat">
        <property resource="application-uat.properties" />
        <appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}.log</file>

            <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %X{host} %X{port} [%thread] %-5level %-40.40logger{39} : %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
                </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>

        </appender>
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>



    <springProfile name="local">
        <property resource="application.properties" />
        <appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}.log</file>

            <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %X{host} %X{port} [%thread]  %-5level  %-40.40logger{39} : %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
                </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>

        </appender>
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long time I got to know the extra log file was created because of the property inside application.properties files.

The below property is honored by spring to create a file also I was mentioning the file name as well as the file path in the logback-spring.xml.

```
logging.file.name=app-Log
```

So whenever I run the application spring see this above property and creates the file in the current working directory and one other file in the specified location in the logback-spring.xml file.

```
${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}.log
```

So if you are mentioning the file name and path do not use the reserved words. I know its a very silly mistake but if it helps anyone then this will not be in vain.