# How to write logs at multiple location in logback-spring.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

Is is possible to create logs at multiple locations using logback-spring.xml ?
I tried doing that but as soon as I give two locations it creates logs at default location .
Below is the mentioned logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <property name="springAppName" value="app-name"/>
    <springProperty name="maxLogHistoryInDays" source="log.maxLogHistoryInDays"/>
    <springProperty name="logPath" source="log.path"/>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy ;HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%level) [%thread] %property{HOSTNAME} ${springAppName:-} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}] 
                %logger{0}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="fileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logPath}/${springAppName}/application.log</file>
        <file>application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>application_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${maxLogHistoryInDays}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy ;HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%thread] %property{HOSTNAME} ${springAppName:-} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}]
                %logger{0}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Here the logs are getting created at default location when two paths are given . And when only path is mentioned i.e., the first one it is working fine , logs are getting created at custom location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208249/logback-spring-xml-creating-multiple-log-files-when-configured-with-springprofil
You can use this as a reference to get your solutions

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible to provide multiple file paths in same appender block but You can do that by adding multiple appender blocks in your config file like -

```
<appender name="fileAppender" ............>
<appender name="fileAppender1" ............>
.
.
<root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
</root>
```

you can provide different file path in different appender blocks. While doing se make sure there is no collision in file. log file name and rolling file name must be different in both.

```
<appender name="fileAppender"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>application_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy ;HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%thread] %property{HOSTNAME} ${springAppName:-} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}]
            %logger{0}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="fileAppender1"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./application1.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>application1_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy ;HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%thread] %property{HOSTNAME} ${springAppName:-} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}]
            %logger{0}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: yes, you can have more than one file appenders in your config.

Comment: @Tomar thanks for the reply . But here also I am getting the error as :```Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting ```

Comment: Looks like you havent configured both appenders properly, specialy file and fileNamePattern must be different in both, I have updated my post with working blocks for your understanding.